# how to store app's data online which can be updated

Tags: java, android, backup

I want to ask that how can i store data on cloud freely so that it can be restored back even after user clears memory of app?

what is good for this purpose firebase ? can it be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Short answer: Firebase is good in your case.
```

> **Pros**

1. Minimum learning curve
2. Quick implementation
3. Easy pricing model
4. Backed by Google - you know you can scale
5. Free plan takes care of concurrent 100 users (~1000 users in a non-concurrent way)

> **Cons**

1. Learning curve for optimization
2. You can never make complex firebase structure as you always need to flatten your data. Hence when you scale and grow complex, it would be an overhead to manage firebase.
3. If implemented badly, and you grow enough to buy paid plans of firebase, may cost you a lot.

> **My suggestion**

If the app you're developing is a quick prototype, a humble app which according to your assumption will be used initially by 1000 people non-concurrently, then you should go ahead and implement Firebase in your app.

Comment: thankyou for this precious answer.but tell me can  i store notifications on cloud  which i send to users ?

Comment: Please always upvote the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: The question you've asked in the post and the question you're asking now are different. I believe your post question was answered well by me. So please accept the answer. It helps the community and encourages people like me to answer more.

Comment: No, currently Firebase won't allow you to **store** notifications. But nonetheless, it will allow you to send text-only notifications without writing any code to send or receive on app-side or server-side. They provide a good UI on their web portal for the same.

Comment: Mayank thanks but i can't vote up because of low reputation.

Comment: Oh. Remember to do so later :)